# How do I install lvextend on CentOS?

Tags: centos, bash

lvextend did not come installed on my CentOS image, how do I install it?

```
# lvextend
-bash: lvextend: command not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily locate a package that contains a program yourself. Try:

```
yum whatprovides */lvextend
```

You'll then be told which package contains the file:

```
lvm2-2.02.111-2.el6_6.1.x86_64 : Userland logical volume management tools
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /sbin/lvextend
```

And then you can install it:

```
yum install lvm2
```

Comment: lol "whatprovides"... never even know that existed

Comment: @WernerCD agreed. I have used `yum search` in the past, which doesn't work for this. It appears `yum whatprovides lvextend` works without the `*/` that's something I plan to remember ;-)